# Jupyter_Widgets_Checkbox_Problem

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

**I have tried in many ways to fix the code so that when I activate/deactivate the box, the message that shows the efic_termica variable does so as well. Also, when you press RUN on the code, the 3 sliders and a large blank space appear. The graph only appears when I move any of the sliders. I think I should add some type of code to update the checkbox value or something similar**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import CoolProp.CoolProp as cp
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, Output, VBox, Checkbox
    
def calcular_ciclo_rankine(P2, P4, efic_iso):
    #Cálculo del estado 1
    P1 = P4 *1e6 #Pa
    x1 = 0
    T1 = cp.PropsSI('T','P', P1,'Q',0,'water') #K
    h1 = cp.PropsSI('H','P', P1,'Q',0,'water') #J/kg
    s1 = cp.PropsSI('S','P', P1,'Q',0,'water') #J/kgK

    #Cálculo del estado 2, suponiendo una bomba isoentrópica
    s2 = s1
    T2 = cp.PropsSI('T','P', P2 * 1e6,'S',s2,'water')
    h2 = cp.PropsSI('H','P', P2 * 1e6,'S',s2,'water')

    #Cálculo del estado 3, suponiendo una temperatura de 500 ºC
    P3 = P2 * 1e6
    T3 = 500 + 273.15
    h3 = cp.PropsSI('H','P', P3,'T',T3,'water')
    s3 = cp.PropsSI('S','P', P3,'T',T3,'water')

    #Cálculo del estado 4s
    P4s = P4 * 1e6
    s4s = s3
    T4s = cp.PropsSI('T','P', P4s,'S',s4s,'water')
    h4s = cp.PropsSI('H','P', P4s,'S',s4s,'water')
    x4s = cp.PropsSI('Q','P', P4s,'S',s4s,'water')

    #Cálculo del estado 4 ==> efic_iso = (h3 - h4) / (h3 - h4s)
    h4 = h3 - (h3 - h4s) * efic_iso
    T4 = cp.PropsSI('T','P', P4 * 1e6,'H',h4,'water')
    s4 = cp.PropsSI('S','P', P4 * 1e6,'H',h4,'water')
    x4 = cp.PropsSI('Q','P', P4 * 1e6,'H',h4,'water')

    #Cálculo del trabajo de la turbina
    wt = h3 - h4

    #Cálculo de la eficiencia térmica
    efic_termica = ((h3 - h4) - (h1 - h2)) / (h3 - h2)

    P = np.array([P1/1e6, P2, P3/1e6, P4, P1/1e6])
    h = np.array([h1, h2, h3, h4, h1])/1000

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    plt.plot(h, P, marker='o', linestyle='-', color='skyblue')
    plt.xlim(0,4000)
    plt.ylim(-1,25)
    plt.xlabel('Entalpía [kJ/kg]')
    plt.ylabel('Presión [MPa]')
    plt.title('Diagrama P-h del Ciclo Rankine Ideal')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

    # Crear un widget Output para mostrar/ocultar efic_termica
    if show_efic_termica_checkbox:
        print(f'η = {efic_termica:.2%}')

    return efic_termica

#Crear controles deslizantes interactivos
P2_slider = widgets.FloatSlider(value=5.0, min=2, max=20.0, step=0.1, description=r'$P_2$'+' (MPa)')
P4_slider = widgets.FloatSlider(value=1.0, min=0.01, max=1.5, step=0.1, description=r'$P_4$'+' (MPa)')
efic_iso_slider = widgets.FloatSlider(value=0.85, min=0.05, max=1.0, step=0.01, description=r'$\eta_{\text{iso}}$')

show_efic_termica_checkbox = Checkbox(value=True, description='Mostrar Eficiencia Térmica')

#Crear la interfaz interactiva
interactive_plot = interactive(calcular_ciclo_rankine, P2=P2_slider, P4=P4_slider, efic_iso=efic_iso_slider, show_efic_termica=show_efic_termica_checkbox)

output = interactive_plot.children[-1]
output.layout.height = '600px'

#Organizar los elementos en un VBox

controls = VBox([P2_slider, P4_slider, efic_iso_slider, show_efic_termica_checkbox])

display(VBox([controls, output]))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.